# How do I sort pandas data frame that has a multi-index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[image: DF I am working with]

Hey guys I got that dataframe that you see in the image and I want to sort it by the first '**всичко**' column the one under 'Общо'.

This is the output when I type:

df.columns =

```
MultiIndex([(     '  Общо',  '  всичко'),
            (     '  Общо',   '   мъже'),
            (     '  Общо',  '    жени'),
            ('В градовете',  '  всичко'),
            ('В градовете',     ' мъже'),
            ('В градовете',     ' жени'),
            (   'В селата', '   всичко'),
            (   'В селата',     ' мъже'),
            (   'В селата',     ' жени')],
           names=['Области', 'Общини'])
```

and

df.index =

```
Index(['Общо за страната', 'Благоевград', 'Банско', 'Белица', 'Благоевград',
       'Гоце Делчев', 'Гърмен', 'Кресна', 'Петрич', 'Разлог',
       ...
       'Нови пазар', 'Смядово', 'Хитрино', 'Шумен', 'Ямбол', 'Болярово',
       'Елхово', 'Стралджа', 'Тунджа', 'Ямбол'],
      dtype='object', length=294)
```

Again, I need to the '**всичко**' column in descending order.

Best regards.

I tried using the df.sort_values() but I am having difficulties working around the MultiIndex

Comment: You more than one columns with level =1 equal to 'всичко'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
df=df.sort_values([('  Общо',  '  всичко')], ascending=False) #define columns names as a tuple
```

Comment: I get a KeyError: ('Общо', 'всичко') when I tried that.

Comment: i edited. Can you check it ?